# How to find the most frequent value in array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have the array of objects "orders". I want to  obtain a first most frequent value in the my array, who often takes a book:

```
orders = [
        {'book' => '1', 'reader' => 'Denis' },
        {'book' => '2', 'reader' => 'Mike' },
        {'book' => '3', 'reader' => 'Denis' },
        {'book' => '3', 'reader' => 'Mike' },
        {'book' => '5', 'reader' => '2' }
        ]
```

I tried this method, but it's good only for arrays of strings: `['string', 'string'...]`:

```
def most_common_value(a)
  a.group_by(&:itself).values.max_by(&:size).first
end
```

Expected result:

```
=> "Denis"
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Ilya, expected  "1"

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What does "the most frequent "reader's" value "1"" mean? Do you want to access the `"reader"` value in the hash? Do you want to find a particular hash in the array? Read "[mcve]" and the linked page. We need to know what your expected return value is: `"1"` or a hash?

Comment: Why is `"1"` most frequent? There are 2 `"1"`s and 2 `"2"`s, so why is `"1"` more frequent than `"2"`?

Comment: @theTinMan i just want to obtain who often takes the book, so i need only my reader's value. Okay, i'll read. That's my first question on stack overflow, sorry)

Comment: @JörgWMittag, a first frequent value

Comment: @theTinMan, JörgWMittag, a little bit refactored my question, thanks for your comments and recommendations

Comment: It's still not clear. You want "Denis", but Denis and Mike both occur twice, which your data seems to say they both should be returned. Why is "Denis" the solution and not `["Denis", "Mike"]`? Is it just because you want the first of the two?

Comment: @theTinMan, but I emphasized that  i want to obtain a first most frequent value in the my array

Comment: So, in other words, if the `order` array had an element for "Mike" first, you would be happy if the result was "Mike"?

Comment: @theTinMan, yes, this is not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
orders = [
  {'book' => '1', 'reader' => 'Denis' },
  {'book' => '2', 'reader' => 'Mike' },
  {'book' => '3', 'reader' => 'Denis' },
  {'book' => '3', 'reader' => 'Mike' },
  {'book' => '5', 'reader' => '2' }
]

orders.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |order, hash| hash[order['reader']] += 1 }.max_by { |k, v| v } 
# => ["Denis", 2]
```

The problem with this is, if there are multiple "max" then the result will be returned based on the order the data is found. For instance, if the order is different:

```
orders.push(orders.shift)
# => [{"book"=>"2", "reader"=>"Mike"},
#     {"book"=>"3", "reader"=>"Denis"},
#     {"book"=>"3", "reader"=>"Mike"},
#     {"book"=>"5", "reader"=>"2"},
#     {"book"=>"1", "reader"=>"Denis"}]
```

the result changes:

```
orders.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |order, hash| hash[order['reader']] += 1 }.max_by { |k, v| v } 
# => ["Mike", 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
key = 'reader'
x = orders.inject({}) do |a,i| 
 a[i[key]] = 0 unless a.has_key? i[key]
 a[i[key]] +=1
 a
end.max_by{|k,v| v}
```

Which returns:

```
=> ["Denis", 2]
```

Comment: If the questions are going to be edited please check if there were already answers, otherwise my response would not make any sense.

Comment: The question should be thought out well in advance, and written concisely and clearly. Minor clarifications are acceptable based on comments to a question, however changing the scope of a question isn't acceptable. These help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256328/vote-to-close-unclear-questions-immediately-after-commenting and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing

Comment: It helps to remember that SO isn't a "help the asker" site, instead, it's a "help those in the future in addition to the asker" site. The person asking has to ask a question that will be useful to others, not just to themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this a few days ago and thought this would be easy if Array or Enumerable had a `mode_by`! Well I finally got around to whipping one up.

### Implementing `mode_by`

A true `mode_by` would probably return a subarray of the items matching a block:

```
orders.mode_by{|order| order['reader']}
#=> [{'book'=>'1', 'reader'=>'Denis'}, {'book'=>'3', 'reader'=>'Denis'}]
```

and to get your desired result:

```
orders.mode_by{|order| order['reader']}.first['reader']
#=> "Denis"
```

So let's implement a `mode_by`:

```
class Array
  def mode_by(&block)
    self.group_by(&block).values.max_by(&:size)
  end
end
```

et voila!

### A custom alternative

In your case, you don't need to return array elements. Let's simplify further by implementing something that returns exactly what you want, the first result of the block that appears the most. We'll call it `mode_of`:

```
class Array
  def mode_of(&block)
    self.group_by(&block).max_by{|k,v| v.size}.first
  end
end
```

Now you can simply do this:

```
orders.mode_of{|order| order['reader']}
#=> "Denis"
```

Answer (score 1):

using [group_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) and [max_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max_by) :

```
orders.group_by { |h| h['reader']}.to_a.max_by {|x| x[1].length}.first
```

Output :

```
 => "Denis"
```